# PostgREST select with joined table where key in joined table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, postgrest

I want to join two tables using PostgREST, with a where condition that looks at the second table.

My code so far:

```
https://127.0.0.1/table_name_1?select=*,table_name_2(column_t2)&table_name_2(column_t2)=ilike.*some_value*
```

This does not work, as it is searching only on table_name_1. Any thoughts what I should change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. Found it :)

For anyone looking :

```
https://127.0.0.1/table_name_1?select=*,table_name_2(column_t2)&table_name_2.column_t2=ilike.*some_value*
```